# Failed asset compilation when attempting to use browserify-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, heroku

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 4.x project and I want to use the `browserify-rails` gem so that I can use CommonJS in some of my JavaScript files. This is working great locally during development, however asset compilation is failing on Heroku. The first problem was the Heroku Ruby buildpack added node 0.4.7 to `/app/bin` and it was first in the `PATH` environment variable. That broke `browserify`. I changed to a Ruby buildpack that does not do this so now my `.buildpack` file looks like this:

```
https://github.com/PROJECT_NAME_HERE/heroku-buildpack-vendorbinaries.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/cymen/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

The error when attempting to compile a JavaScript asset that uses CommonJS `require` (so triggers `browserify-rails`):

```
   rake aborted!
   Error while running `/tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/node_modules/.bin/browserify --list`:
   /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
   (in /tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/app/assets/javascripts/designer.js)/tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/browserify-rails-f3df1d20b466/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:92:in `run_browserify'
   /tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/browserify-rails-f3df1d20b466/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:40:in `dependencies'
   /tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/browserify-rails-f3df1d20b466/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:33:in `asset_dependencies'
   /tmp/build_a95a51d0-fdb1-4035-ad56-97c40f738540/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/browserify-rails-f3df1d20b466/lib/browserify-rails/browserify_processor.rb:13:in `evaluate'
   ...
```

So it appears the node binary is not accessible during the Ruby on Rails build step. Is this because node is in a location that the `PATH` settings for the Ruby buildpack do not include `/app/vendor/node/bin/node`? I tried adding a `postinstall` to `packages.json` like so:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ln -s /app/vendor/node/bin/node /app/bin/node"
}
...
```

But that didn't help. Next I'm going to try digging into the ruby buildpack that I forked and see if I can tinker with the path. But this is a very slow process with the round trip time to deploy to Heroku so if someone else knows what is wrong, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer turns out to be:

When Heroku uses a multi-buildpack build like we are, all of the builds happen in a random directory in `/tmp` and nothing is put into the regular directories like `/app` until the whole build is completed. The solution to my problem was:

1. Fork the [Heroku Ruby buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby)
2. Remove the build in old NodeJS 0.4.7 binary or instead fork a buildpack that already has it removed ([mattwalters heroku-buildpack-ruby](https://github.com/mattwalters/heroku-buildpack-ruby))
3. Edit .buildpacks and make sure you have the Heroku NodeJS buildpack above the Ruby buildpack
4. Update the heroku-buildpack-ruby so that it upates the PATH using during slug compile to include the NodeJS directories created in `/tmp` by the Heroku NodeJS buildpack

To make things easier, I've forked `mattwalters` Heroku Ruby buildpack and added the code to update the path: https://github.com/cymen/heroku-buildpack-ruby

The end result is that when the asset compliation happens **during slug compile**, the PATH now has a recent NodeJS binary in it so that browserify-rails works! Note that browserify-rails is still pretty rough so you may need to make custom tweaks to it to make things work properly ([I have a fork that excludes vendor and jasmine from modularization](https://github.com/cymen/browserify-rails)).

An alternative is to use the stock Heroku Ruby buildpack but following the guide under "Hacking" to use your own version of NodeJS: [Hacking](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#hacking)

Answer (score 1):

Heroku's latest Ruby buildpacks (`v113+`) use the Node.js buildpack's `node` binary, so you just need to have multi buildpacks set up with access to the latest Ruby and Node.js buildpacks.

Here's my `.buildpacks` file:

`https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v63
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#v129`

And everything should work!